# Should the user be logged in when clicking on the verify email link?

Tags: registration, email, confirmation, onboarding, email-verification

- I have a webapp with signp/signin
- User does a signup with email password or a sign in via Google Twitter Facebook or GitHub
- If user is new, then an email is sent to this user to verify their email account while they get redirected to the home page
- This email contains a link like https://example.com/verify/4f476f1a9c861ddc3... a random token generated for that user and saved to database
- The user may open the email immediately or may open it after a few hours
- In say 24 hours, the link will expire
- Should the user be logged in when clicking this link?
- What should happen if the user is logged out?
- Also when the user clicks verify email to generate a link? should a new token be generated each time? Is there a limit here to prevent getting attacked by some hacker?

Answer (score 1):

Even time expiration limit not necessary for each application usecase, there is not much difference when a user is logged in or out within this frame.

- Simply first, it should be checked if user already logged in and if
  not, user should asked to complete login informations which prompted
  before redirecting the user to verification grant. That means not
  necessarily user has to be signed in during clicking this link.
- And as I mentioned above, you should first force users to sign in to
  be able to grant their verifications.
- For your third question **`"Also when the user clicks verify email to generate a link?"`**, since you clarified the situtation with a
  comment below, then you may automatically send a verification e-mail
  without any further action by user right after the account is created
  (means signed up). Plus, you may give your users ability to view
  `re-send` option within the same area instead of letting them send
  first time, since it's necessary for every user.
- For the rest of this question, I'll share my opinions other than
  experience since I haven't done a complete system like you described
  above. I can think of generating a single token valid for 24 hours
  even generating a token therefore a link is not so complex. Letting
  users be able to send this verification a reasonable amount of time
  (to say, a couple of times for each day) satisfy my point of view in
  ideation.
- By this way, while you may limit the verification request to say 3
  times a day, you encounter the attacking probability and save your
  resources. For the users can't still get a verification mail, you may
  try to include SMS technologies or some other alternative ways to
  grant access.

Comment: i plan to add a monthly subscription payment gateway to my website so email verification would be essential to bill

Comment: I edited my answer as above.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a common scenario is:

1. User clicks link in their Email
2. A tab in their browser opens, with some text like "Account Successfully Activated".

And that's it, the screen stays in there with the message. It does
**not** redirect to the website. Slack, Zoom and other services to this. Or at least they acknowledge that they will redirect the user, but the user needs to click a button to advance.

Consider that some users have disabilities and it might take a while for them to read your message, so it might be confusing if you redirect them without their permission.

- About token generation, you should limit it after X tries in Y minutes.

Comment: what happens when you click that link in that email and user is logged out on that website?

Comment: @PirateApp: Some websites leave the user logged out, it just acknowledges that the account has been activated.


It might help to create a user flow to visualize all possible scenarios.